# Errno 13 Permission denied: '/storage/emulated/0/Download/ on honor kivy

Tags: android, python-3.x, permissions, kivy

I have a problem when I try to read a picture from /storage/emulated/0/Download/ using the open function and the kivy framework

encode_bmp = open(f'/storage/emulated/0/Download/encoded

It doesn't work on honor 10 lite with android 10 and EMUI and redmi with android 12 and MIUI but it works on motorola g32 with android 12. Is it a problem with EMUI and MIUI?
android.permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

```
def on_start(self):
    if platform == 'android':
        from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
        request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
```

Comment: You did not tell which problem. And you did not post code.

Comment: encode_bmp = open(f'/storage/emulated/0/Download/encoded.bmp
it dont work on honor 10 lite and Redmi but work on mototrola g32

Comment: You did not tell which problem. And you should post your code in your post. Not as a comment. Write a good post.

Comment: https://chat.kivy.org/